# How to proxy a class's methods dynamically?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to proxy "all" methods of a class using following code:

```
import paramiko

class SFTPProxy():
    def __init__(self, sftp):
        self.sftp = TRANSPORT.open_sftp_client()
        for x, y in type(self.sftp).__dict__.items():
            if re.search(r'^__', x):
                continue
            def fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return y(self.sftp, *args, **kwargs)
            setattr(SFTPProxy, x, fn)
```

When I call the method like this:

```
fooproxy.sftp.listdir()
```

It works.

When I call the method like this:

```
fooproxy.listdir()  # this is the method belongs to the proxied class
```

The program just hangs, is there any shallow problems in the code?

Comment: just for the reference, why usual inheritance is not ok?

Comment: @Marat A proxy usually needs to do something before/after calling the original method, looks like he left that out to simplify the example.

Comment: @Barmar, and you can call super() from inherited methods, too. So, why this approach?

Comment: You'd have to create a new subclass for every class you want to proxy, instead of just doing `fooproxy = SFTPProxy(OtherClass)`

Comment: @Barmar, makes sense.

Comment: @Marat The class is for RPC, so I have to use proxy mode, proxied class could not be used in RPC due to some limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I can see with your approach is that not all values in `type(self.sftp).__dict__` are functions. Hence, `y(...)` will fail. Isn't it simpler and cleaner to override [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

```
class SFTPProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, sftp):
        self.sftp = TRANSPORT.open_sftp_client()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if hasattr(self.sftp, item):
            return getattr(self.sftp, item)
        raise AttributeError(item)
```

This will handle all kinds of attributes rather swiftly: instance/class fields, instance/class/static methods.