# Is it possible for a class to provide convenient direct access to the methods of specific objects initialised within it?

Tags: python, class

This may be highly abnormal, but I feel like it may be a useful thing. I have a range of classes that do different jobs in my package. I want to keep them seperate to keep the logic modular, and allow advanced users to use the classess directly, but I also want users to have a main convenience class that gives them quick access to the methods defined in these other classes. So to provide an example, currently this works...

```
class Tail:
    def wag_tail(self):
        print('Wag Wag')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = Tail()


my_dog = Dog()
my_dog.tail.wag_tail()
>> Wag Wag
```

But... is it possible to adjust my `Dog` class so that this also works?

```
my_dog.wag_tail()
>> Wag Wag
```

Editing for clarity.

I want to achieve the above, but automatically, without necessarily having to define a new method in `Dog` e.g. you could manually ensure access via `def wag_tail(self): self.tail.wag_tail()`, but what if I wanted to avoid writing a convenience access method every time I add a method to my `Tail` class. Is there a way to set things up such that `Tail` methods are always accessible from `Dog`?

Comment: As in `def wag_tail(self): self.tail.wag_tail()`? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes, but without having to manually define the additional method. Kind of like inheritence but I might have a `self.tail`, a `self.legs` etc and want to access their methods direct from a `Dog` instance.

Comment: No. You can *automate* this kind of delegation by defining `__getattr__` appropriately, but that can be a bit fragile and it's still you writing some additional code.

Comment: I guess you will have to decide between inheritance (which would be wrong in this case because a dog is not a tail) or writing the convenience methods.

Comment: Consider this: what if `Dog` had *two* attributes, both of which referred to instances of `Tail`. What would you want `my_dog.wag_tail()` to do in that case? Or what if your `tail` and `legs` attributes both had different definitions of a method named `stretch`; what should `my_dog.stretch()` do?

Comment: Or maybe `Tail` and `Leg` had some common method, for example `__str__` should those also be copied over? Maybe you declared a method on `Dog` and `Tail` also has that method what should happen? Also note if your question is only "_Is there a way_" then the answer is also simply "Yes"

Comment: My laziness is coming up against reality, but that's ok! @chepner provides a good example of why this being fully automatic doesn't make sense. Friedrich reinforces that I need to write something at least to make those connections.

Comment: @chepner do you know of an example somewhere of overloading `__getattr__` to get this kind of behaviour? At this point I'm just curious if it may be useful in some limited cases - fragility of using it noted.

Comment: @JamesAllen-Robertson see: [How to proxy a class's methods dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043808/how-to-proxy-a-classs-methods-dynamically) You can also play around a bit with `type` and creating your class dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar.  You can pass in the owning class to the `__init__` of the method class and have it append it's method back to the owning class.

Here any class that inherits from `PassThrough` will run through it's own attributes and append any public methods to a parent class.  You just have to pass the `self` of the owning class.

```
class PassThrough:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        if not parent:
            return
        for method_name in dir(self):
            if not method_name.startswith('_'):
                method = getattr(self, method_name)
                setattr(parent, method_name, method)
          

class Tail(PassThrough):
    def wag_tail(self):
        print('Wag Wag')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = Tail(self)

dog = Dog()
dog.wag_tail()
# prints: Wag Wag
```

You can also pass methods upward through multiple layers by using `super()`.  Here we create a `Tongue` class, and then a `Head` class that has a tongue.  Then add a head to the `Dog` class.

```
class Tongue(PassThrough):
    def lick(self):
        print('Lick Lick')

class Head(PassThrough):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.tongue = Tongue(self)
        # this passes the appended method from Tongue to the parent.
        super().__init__(parent)

    def shake_head(self):
        print('Fwop fwop')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = Tail(self)
        self.head = Head(self)

dog = Dog()
dog.lick()
dog.shake_head()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [the `__getattr__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#object.__getattr__) is made for:

```
class Tail:
    def wag_tail(self):
        print('Wag Wag')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = Tail()

    # Only new code is this two-line method definition
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.tail, name)
```

`__getattr__` is called when an attribute (including method) is looked up on an instance and the attribute is not found; when that happens, the `__getattr__` is invoked with an argument of the name being looked for. [The `getattr` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) can then be used to look it up on contained object(s).

If you have *many* such contained classes, you'll need to define some absolute ordering for checking, and check them one-by-one, so if you needed to check for behaviors of `self.tongue` and `self.paw` for instance, in that order, you might implement it as:

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for internalname in ('tail', 'tongue', 'paw'):
            internalattr = getattr(self, internalname)
            try:
                return getattr(internalattr, name)
            except AttributeError:
                continue  # Try the next
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

One caveat: When looking up *special* methods (those that begin and end with `__`, usually used to implement features that Python uses implicitly via syntax or built-in functions, e.g. `__len__` for `len(x)` and `__add__` for `x + y`), Python typically bypasses instance lookup, along with the special attribute access interception methods (`__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`), so you can't use this to handle operator overloading and the like. In that case, you'll have to hand-write (or programmatically generate code for and `eval`) the proxying methods individually.